# What is the @ sign added as a suffix to images used for apps based in the Ubuntu SDK?

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-sdk

I've been looking at some example apps from the Ubuntu SDK and from the Touch Developer Preview source code, and I've noticed that some images used as assets in those apps have a suffix with an @ sign followed by a number. E.g. `avatar@8.png`

What is the purpose of naming images like that?

Answer (score 7):

This is related to [Resolution Independence](http://developer.ubuntu.com/api/ubuntu-12.10/qml/mobile/resolution-independence.html) in the Ubuntu SDK. Currently the documentation for this part is missing, but it [should be added soon](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-ui-toolkit/+bug/1092051).

Taking the `avatar@8.png` image file name as an example, the `@8` suffix refers to the [DPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dots_per_inch) in which the original image was created.

That information will be used in the resolution independence calculations that will happen when scaling the image. When referencing to the image in the code, you should use the name without the suffix, e.g. `avatar.png`